# Change value associated with keys using alternatives

Tags: associations

I have a List of Associations that contains a Key called "ClaimBasis".  There are about 10 possible values that ClaimBasis can take on, one of them being the value Null.  I want all values that are equal to "Risks Attaching" to be changed to "RA".  I want all other values for ClaimBasis to be changed to "LO".  I originally tried to do this with an if statement, but the Null values caused me a problem.  Below is what I am currently doing, and it works for now.

```
cBasis = Complement[
Union[#[ClaimBasis] & /@ businessAssoc], {"Risks Attaching"}];

businessAssoc = businessAssoc /. Alternatives @@ cBasis -> "LO" 
/. "Risks Attaching" -> "RA";
```

My concern is that in some future case I may have Null values assigned to other Keys in my List of Associations, and I wouldn't want to change them.  The way I've been adjusting values in a List of Associations is as follows:

```
accAssoc = <|#, "Year" -> Floor[#Year]|> & /@ accAssoc;
```

or even

```
elrAssoc = <|#, If[#[EPI] != 0, LR -> #[Loss]/#[EPI], LR -> 0]|> & /@ elrAssoc;
```

What I would like to know is whether there's a sensible way to use Alternatives when changing a value for a specific Key in a List of Associations.  Perhaps my "default" method for setting values in a List of Associations is not the best way to do it, in which case I'd appreciate knowing a better alternative.

Sample data as requested:

```
businessAssoc[[;; 15]]

{<|Treaty -> "<N/A>", Effective -> {1925, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> Null|>,
<|Treaty -> "14700", Effective -> {2007, 7, 1, 0, 0, 1.}, ClaimBasis -> "Occurrence"|>,
<|Treaty -> "87299", Effective -> {2001, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> Null|>,
<|Treaty -> "IN0004", Effective -> {1980, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "<None>"|>,
<|Treaty -> "ABC0002", Effective -> {1988, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "<None>"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TRES500B", Effective -> {2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Losses Occurring"|>,
<|Treaty -> "YYYY434", Effective -> {2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Losses Occurring"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TT48425", Effective -> {2003, 11, 3, 0, 1, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Occurrence"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TY4176A", Effective -> {2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Losses Occurring"|>,
<|Treaty -> "MBM0001", Effective -> {1989, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "<None>"|>,
<|Treaty -> "EEML216C", Effective -> {2007, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Losses Occurring"|>,
<|Treaty -> "78820", Effective -> {1994, 6, 12, 0, 1, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Claims Made"|>,
<|Treaty -> "AMUT0004", Effective -> {1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Losses Occurring"|>,
<|Treaty -> "CMMM0028", Effective -> {1997, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Losses Occurring"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TYCS1234", Effective -> {2012, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "Risks Attaching"|>}
```

After the adjustment:

```
businessAssoc[[;; 15]]

{<|Treaty -> "<N/A>", Effective -> {1925, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
 <|Treaty -> "14700", Effective -> {2007, 7, 1, 0, 0, 1.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> 87299", Effective -> {2001, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "IN0004", Effective -> {1980, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "ABC0002", Effective -> {1988, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TRES500B", Effective -> {2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>, 
<|Treaty -> "YYYY434", Effective -> {2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TT48425", Effective -> {2003, 11, 3, 0, 1, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TY4176A", Effective -> {2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "MBM0001", Effective -> {1989, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>, 
<|Treaty -> "EEML216C", Effective -> {2007, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>, 
<|Treaty -> "78820", Effective -> {1994, 6, 12, 0, 1, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "AMUT0004", Effective -> {1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "CMMM0028", Effective -> {1997, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "LO"|>,
<|Treaty -> "TYCS1234", Effective -> {2012, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, ClaimBasis -> "RA"|>}
```

Comment: It will be much easier to answer if you provide some sample data, to make your question self - contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Albert Retey's answer but without in-place modification, you can use [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[
 Replace[{"Risks Attaching" -> "RA", _ -> "LO"}],
 businessAssoc,
 {All, Key @ ClaimBasis}
]
```

[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) can also be used:

```
<|#, ClaimBasis -> (#[ClaimBasis] /. {"Risks Attaching" -> "RA", _ -> "LO"})|> & /@
  businessAssoc
```

Comment: I like the one using Map and Function.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure whether that solves all the questions you have, but one of the really good things about `Associations` is that you can set content in place, like:

```
businessAssoc[[All, Key@ClaimBasis]] = Replace[
  businessAssoc[[All, Key@ClaimBasis]], {
   "Risks Attaching" -> "RA",
   _ -> "LO"
  },
  {1}
 ]
```

with the above you are only changing values associated to the `ClaimBasis`-key, so you don't even have to care about what values there are for the other keys...

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing another part of your question, Consider this alternative method of updating a list of associations.

```
SeedRandom[1];
d1 = Table[Association["x" -> i, "y" -> RandomReal[{1950, 2000}]], {i, 10000}];
AbsoluteTiming[d1[[All, "y"]] = Floor[data[[All, "y"]]];]
```

> ```
> {0.008784, Null}
> ```

The above tests out as faster than the method you propose.

```
SeedRandom[1];
d2 = Table[Association["x" -> i, "y" -> RandomReal[{1950, 2000}]], {i, 10000}];
AbsoluteTiming[d2 = <|#, "y" -> Floor[#y]|> & /@ d2;]
```

> ```
> {0.030963, Null}
> ```